# Modify wordpress title tag

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have added title tag in my site by `title-tag` theme feature.

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

For some pages i want to modify that title. [The hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/) available applies to `wp_title()` function. Any hook available to override this title added through theme support?

Comment: Use `wp_title` filter that will allow you to add custom title.

Comment: @raju_eww But that filter has no effect now as title is added through theme feature `title-tag`

Comment: Please check this answer this may help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504844/overwrite-title-tag-using-a-wordpress-plugin